# Dimension of a finite dimensional space of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

$\newcommand{\pos}{\operatorname{pos}}$$p$ is a polynomial on $\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R$ and $\phi$ is an arbitrary real function. Let $G$ be a collection of real-valued functions on a set $X$. Define the positivity set of $G$ as
$$\pos(G) := \{\pos(g) : g\in G\},\quad \pos(g) := \{x : g(x) > 0\}. $$
How to prove that the family of sets
$$\{\{(s,u):p((t-s)/h,u)\geq \phi(u)\}:t\in\mathbb R^d, h>0 \} $$
is contained in the family of positivity sets of a finite dimensional space of functions?

This question comes from Page 911 of this paper http://www.numdam.org/article/AIHPB_2002__38_6_907_0.pdf.

I think the key is to prove that $p((t-s)/h,u)- \phi(u)$ belongs to a function space with finite dimension. Say the order of polynomial $p$ is $m$. I know that $p$ belongs to a space spanned by $1,x,\ldots,x^m$, so $p$ belongs to a function space with finite dimension $m+1$. Then what about $p-\phi$? Will the dimension be $m+2$??